# Import tables from .sql to sqlite, incomplete SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

I am trying to import tables from a database in an SQL Server to an SQLite database. Nevertheless, I think that the file tables.sql is not complete or correctly written. 
From SQL Server Management Studio, I generated a script (tables.sql) selecting only some tables from the database. This file looks like this (with two tables) :

```
USE [MYDATABASE]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] ON 

INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] ([TABLE_ONE_ID], [TABLE_ONE_MNEMO], [TABLE_ONE_DESC], [AUTO_ANALYSIS], [SCOPE_LEVEL], [IN_ABV], [TABLE_ONE_ORDER], [REPORT_ATA]) VALUES (37, N'GENERAL', N'GENERAL', N'N', 3, 0, 1, N'GEN')
...
GO
...
INSERT [dbo].[TEST_POINT_TYPE] ([TEST_POINT_TYPE_ID], [TEST_POINT_TYPE_MNEMO], [TEST_POINT_TYPE_DESC], [AUTO_ANALYSIS], [SCOPE_LEVEL], [IN_PATM], [TEST_POINT_TYPE_ORDER], [REPORT_ATA]) VALUES (207, N'LDMCR', N'LDMCR', N'N', 1, 1, 999, N'70')
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_ONE] OFF
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_TWO] ON

INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_TWO] ([TBT_ID], [TABLE_ONE_ID], [SUBPROGRAM_ID], [VALUE], [DESCRIPTION], [ETE], [SUBPROGRAM_CONTEXT], [IS_HOHO], [TEST_VISIBLE], [COMPLETION_ONLY], [CUPTER_NM_CHECKED_WORD], [CUPTER_NM_CHECKED_MAIN], [CUPTER_NM_CHECKED_MORE]) VALUES (1, NULL, 5, NULL, N'Air conditioning checks', N'21', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
...
GO
...
INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_TWO] ([TBT_ID], [TABLE_ONE_ID], [SUBPROGRAM_ID], [VALUE], [DESCRIPTION], [ETE], [SUBPROGRAM_CONTEXT], [IS_HOHO], [TEST_VISIBLE], [COMPLETION_ONLY], [CUPTER_NM_CHECKED_WORD], [CUPTER_NM_CHECKED_MAIN], [CUPTER_NM_CHECKED_MORE]) VALUES (39, NULL, 5, NULL, N'Auto call-outs', N'31', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TABLE_TWO] OFF
```

Now, if I try the following command :

```
cat tables.sql | sqlite3 MYDATABASE.db
```

I have the following statement

```
Error: incomplete SQL: ▒▒U
```

I suppose that something is missing in the tables.sql file and I tried to add this at the beginning :

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS [MYDATABASE]
```

But it doesn't change anything. What may I change/add to complete the tables.sql file ? Then here is just an example with two tables, in reality I have much more tables and items.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does SQlite really accept that SQL Server syntax?

Comment: Well, I don't really know. I am looking for a solution to import this data into an SQLite db and I didn't find another "easy" way at this moment. Importing data from a .sql file seems to be the most common way.
Edit : Now, if you know what do I have to change in the syntax it would be perfect

Comment: I don't know SQlite very well. (I just recognized the syntax as SQL Server style.)

Comment: Ok fine, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script uses lots of SQL Server-specific features that are not supported by SQLite.

SQLite has no `CREATE DATABASE`, `USE`, `SET`, or `GO`. Remove them.

SQLite has no schemans (not in the same way as SQL Server, only for attached databases). Remove all `[dbo].` prefixes.

SQLite strings always are Unicode. Remove the `N` prefixes.

SQLite happens to supports SQL Server's `[`/`]` quoting.

There is no `▒▒U` in the code you've shown, so there are likely to be other problems …

Comment: Thank you CL. I will try to do that, and maybe write a script to do all the modifications because I have hundreds of lines. So finally, I understand that it is a problem of syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your help @CL. It works. Now, I'd like to add another advice if someone needs it, I had to use the command dos2unix to convert the tables.sql file (I am working on Linux with files from Windows).